# Are commercial chocolate almonds coated with something that prevents melting?

Tags: chocolate, melting-chocolate

Why is it that a milk chocolate bar begins to melt in my hand sooner than a chocolate-covered almond?

The surface of typical chocolate-covered almonds are also a lot smoother than regular chocolate bars when I slide my finger around each of their surfaces.

And does the shiny surface of the chocolate-covered almond have anything to do with its ability to not melt so easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aren't coated, but the chocolate is mixed with hardeners. Things like xanthan gum, gum Arabic, corn starch, bees wax, etc.

These let the chocolate harden and polish a little better.